# Xamarin Forms HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm trying to use the HttpWebRequest class to send a request to my server to retrieve some data, but the .ContentLength propertly isnt available to me, though in any other C# app (Winforms, Console) it is...

I've looked for so many answers and I just cannot find something that works

The project: Xamarin.Forms (Portable Class Library) for multi platforms

Full error:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'HttpWebRequest' does not contain a definition for 'ContentLength' and no extension method 'ContentLength' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpWebRequest' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the HttpWebRequest contentLength property in Xamarin Forms you can access it via [DependencyService](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/) you will come to  find some things are just not available in the xamarin portable library you can find more info on that [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/pcl/introduction_to_portable_class_libraries/)

So In Your Portable Library create a interface  example below

```
public interface IMyspace
{
   string result(string url);
}
```

Then In Your Actual Android Or IOS or whatever Project create a class inheriting your interface

```
public class MyClass : IMyspace
{    
    public string result(string url)
    {
      var target = new System.Uri(url);
      var httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest) HttpWebRequest.Create(target);
        //do whatever stuff you trying to do here and just return  
          whatever you want 
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is this necessary? The implementation is the exact same but I cannot add it to my PCL